# How to emit an event from a nuxt plugin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Code:

```js
export default ({ app }, inject: (key: string, value: any) => void) => {
  // doesn't work
  app.$emit('eventname', 'value')
})
```

I want to emit an event from a plugin from the component.

`app.$emit()` throws an error `app.$emit is not a function`

Comment: If I remember well it should be app.$nuxt.$emit.

Comment: @drocha87 no, it's not. I inspected `app` variable, it doesn't have `$nuxt`, but it has `nuxt` which has no `$emit` method available.

Comment: Yeah you right, well you could than access it through window.$nuxt.$emit but I'm not sure if this is good practice any way.

Comment: i think i'll better use an event bus approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142572/how-do-you-emit-an-event-from-a-nuxt-plugin

Comment: Despite window.$nuxt is accessible only on client side [context helpers](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/concepts/context-helpers#nuxt-the-nuxtjs-helper)

Answer (score 3):

After look at the nuxt plugins documentation, I found a possible solution to this problem. I defined my plugin as follow

plugins/hello.ts

```js
import { Context } from '@nuxt/types';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default function (_ctx: Context, inject: Function) {
  const hello = function (this: Vue, msg: string) {
    console.log('emitting', msg);

    if (process.server) {
      console.log('server side');
    } else {
      console.log('client side');
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      this.$nuxt.$emit('hello', msg);
    }, 5000);
  } // Event Bus 
   .bind(new Vue());

  inject('hello', hello);
}
```

Pay attention that I used anonymous `function(...){}` and not an arrow function `() => {...}`. **Updated** don't forget to `bind(new Vue())` the event bus otherwise if you call `this.$alert` in your vuex store `this` will be an instance of Store and not Vue as expected.

And I'm using it as the follow

page/something.vue

```js
...
mounted() {
    this.$hello('test');
    this.$nuxt.$on('hello', (val: string) => {
      alert(val);
    });
},
...
```

And it works as expected! As I'm using typescript I need to defined `this` as Vue to avoid `this.$nuxt` is not defined error.

And in my nuxt.config.js

```
...
 plugins: [
    // '~/plugins/axios'
    { src: '~plugins/vuedraggable.ts' },
    { src: '~plugins/hello.ts' },
  ],
...
```

I hope this help you somehow.

**Updated:**

If you are using typescript and wants to merge (Module Augmentation) `$hello` so it becomes visible in both `Vue` instance, `Context` and `Vuex` store, you can include this piece of code in the same file of your plugin in our case  `plugins/hello.ts`

```js
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  // Vue instance this.$hello
  interface Vue {
    $hello(msg: string): void;
  }
}

declare module '@nuxt/types' {
  // NuxtAppOtions this.app.$hello
  interface NuxtAppOptions {
    $hello(msg: string): void;
  }
  // Accessible by Context
  interface Context {
    $hello(msg: string): void;
  }
}

declare module 'vuex/types/index' {
  // this.$hello inside Vuex stores
  interface Store<S> {
    $hello(msg: string): void;
  }
}
```

And that is it.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation with typescript

### Create a global eventBus using Vue

#### `plugins/event-bus.ts`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Plugin } from '@nuxt/types'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $bus: Vue
  }
}

declare module '@nuxt/types' {
  interface NuxtAppOptions {
    $bus: Vue
  }
  interface Context {
    $bus: Vue
  }
}

declare module 'vuex/types/index' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  interface Store<S> {
    $bus: Vue
  }
}

const eventBus = new Vue()

const eventBusPlugin: Plugin = (_, inject) => {
  inject('bus', eventBus)
}

export default eventBusPlugin
```

Don't forget to declare your plugin in `nuxt.config.ts`. It must be in the first place like below:

```js
...

  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/event-bus', // <--- here
    '~/plugins/filter',
    '~/plugins/analytics',
    '~/plugins/sentry',
    '~/plugins/vuetify',
    '~/plugins/copy-clipboard',
    '~/plugins/vee-validate',
    '~/plugins/moment',
    '~/plugins/icons',
  ],

...
```

#### Using eventBus in other plugin `plugins/analytics.ts`

```js
import { Plugin } from '@nuxt/types'

const analytics: Plugin = ({ $bus }) => {
  $bus.$on('mark-has-payed', (args: any) => console.log(args))
}
export default analytics
```

#### Using eventBus in component `components/MyComponent.ts`

```
<template>
 ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class extends Vue {
  markHasPayed() {
    this.$bus.$emit('mark-has-payed', { payment: 'Visa' })
  }
}
</script>
```